# ros2 using cpp ament package library in another cpp ament package

Tags: ros2, cmake, rclcpp, ament

i'm trying to transform ego-planner-swarm founded in:
https://github.com/ZJU-FAST-Lab/ego-planner-swarm
to ros2...

in my ros2 workspace, i have 3 packages...

bspline_opt(as library)

plan_manage

traj_utils(as library)

in plan manage i want to use other two packages as library... the problem is, i only can use whats in the header files of these two library packages in plan manage package!

for example consider this function reference:

```
static PolynomialTraj minSnapTraj(const Eigen::MatrixXd &Pos, const Eigen::Vector3d &start_vel,
                                    const Eigen::Vector3d &end_vel, const Eigen::Vector3d &start_acc,
                                    const Eigen::Vector3d &end_acc, const Eigen::VectorXd &Time);
```

in header file polynomial_traj.h.

its full definition:

```
PolynomialTraj PolynomialTraj::minSnapTraj(const Eigen::MatrixXd &Pos, const Eigen::Vector3d &start_vel,
                                           const Eigen::Vector3d &end_vel, const Eigen::Vector3d &start_acc,
                                           const Eigen::Vector3d &end_acc, const Eigen::VectorXd &Time)
{
  .
  .
  .
}
```

is in polynomial_traj.cpp. this function is in traj_utils package and its cmake is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(traj_utils)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(builtin_interfaces REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/Bspline.msg"
  "msg/DataDisp.msg"
  "msg/MultiBsplines.msg"
  "msg/PositionCommand.msg"
  DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs std_msgs builtin_interfaces # Add packages that above messages depend on, in this case geometry_msgs for Sphere.msg
)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(SYSTEM
  ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})

  # Find the other package (replace 'other_package' with the actual name)
find_package(bspline_opt REQUIRED)

# Add include directories for the other package
include_directories(${bspline_opt_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)

add_library(polynomial_traj src/polynomial_traj.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(polynomial_traj
  rclcpp
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  bspline_opt)

  ament_target_dependencies(polynomial_traj bspline_opt)
  

target_include_directories(polynomial_traj PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
target_compile_features(polynomial_traj PUBLIC c_std_99 cxx_std_17)  # Require C99 and C++17

install(TARGETS polynomial_traj
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

# Install header files
install(DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_export_include_directories(include)

ament_package()
```

now i want to use this function in plan manage package so i include:

```
#include <traj_utils/polynomial_traj.h>
```

but when i use the function in plan_manage package, it only gets the reference which is in polynomial_traj.h and not the full definition of function and i get

> "undefined reference to...(function name)"

while building with colcon...
here is my plan_manage cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(plan_manage)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED)
find_package(nav_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(visualization_msgs REQUIRED)

# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(SYSTEM
  ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

find_package(bspline_opt REQUIRED)
find_package(traj_utils REQUIRED)

# Add include directories for the other package
include_directories(${bspline_opt_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${traj_utils_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(ego_planner_node src/ego_planner_node.cpp
                                src/ego_replan_fsm.cpp
                                src/planner_manager.cpp)

add_executable(traj_server src/traj_server.cpp)

add_executable(InTransform src/InTransform.cpp)

add_executable(TransformOut_position src/TransformOut_position.cpp)

add_executable(TransformOut_vel src/TransformOut_vel.cpp)
                                
target_include_directories(ego_planner_node PRIVATE include)  # Assuming your headers are in the include directory
target_include_directories(traj_server PRIVATE include)
target_include_directories(InTransform PRIVATE include)
target_include_directories(TransformOut_position PRIVATE include)
target_include_directories(TransformOut_vel PRIVATE include)

ament_target_dependencies(ego_planner_node
  rclcpp
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  visualization_msgs
  bspline_opt
  traj_utils)

ament_target_dependencies(traj_server
  rclcpp
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  visualization_msgs
  bspline_opt
  traj_utils)

ament_target_dependencies(InTransform
  rclcpp
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  visualization_msgs
  bspline_opt
  traj_utils)

  ament_target_dependencies(TransformOut_position
  rclcpp
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  visualization_msgs
  bspline_opt
  traj_utils)

  ament_target_dependencies(TransformOut_vel
  rclcpp
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  visualization_msgs
  bspline_opt
  traj_utils)


ament_target_dependencies(ego_planner_node bspline_opt traj_utils) 

ament_target_dependencies(traj_server bspline_opt traj_utils)

target_include_directories(ego_planner_node PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
target_compile_features(ego_planner_node PUBLIC c_std_99 cxx_std_17)  # Require C99 and C++17

install(TARGETS
  ego_planner_node
  traj_server  # Add this line to install traj_server
  InTransform
  TransformOut_position
  TransformOut_vel
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

  # Install header files
install(DIRECTORY include/
DESTINATION include
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_export_include_directories(include)

# Install launch files.
install(DIRECTORY
  launch
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_package()
```

should i include the cpp files also? or there is something wrong with cmake? or is it some other problem entirely?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Please mention the error message in your question. Consider concising the code snippet by sharing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).